# NSManagedObjectContext Batch Save Limit

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios6

I'm currently working on an iOS app using CoreData.

When the app is started for the first time a series of web requests are made against RESTful web service.

The web service serves up a series of json responses which can contain upwards of 2000 records.

These records are then parsed, transformed into various core data entities and stored within our SQLite persistence store.

Once this operation is complete we create an object graph by fetching all the rows within **Entity A** (for example) and create an object graph we use at a later time.

For some reason, while iterating through all NSManagedObjects stored within **Entity A** some NSManagedObjects have missing property values.

Given that we're working in a multi-threaded environment, we've made sure that we're creating separate managedObjectContexts on separate threads - however, during our most recent test runs, we've configured the environment such that only one thread is saving/retrieving data from the SQLite persistence store at a time.

It may also be worth noting that we don't perform a **`[context save:...]`** operation until we've parsed all 2000+ records that have come back in a json response.

After some trial and error, I've noticed that the problem goes away is we perform a save every insert.

For example, the following code will work ok:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ...
NSError *error = ...

for(id record in collectionOfRecords){
    //create entity for insertion
    [context save:&error]
}
```

But this will cause the issue of missing property values:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ...
NSError *error = ...

for(id record in collectionOfRecords){
    //create entity for insertion     
}
[context save:&error]
```

**Question:**

Is there a maximum number of NSManagedObjects that can sit in memory before an **`[NSManagedObjectContext save:...]`** operation must be performed?

Comment: Are they missing, or are they faulted? The max number you can have in memory is limited by your free memory. What it sounds like you are seeing is that the changes aren't being propagated between threads until you save - which is normal.

Comment: They literally come back as 'nil'. Another thing I forgot to mention - give the way error handling is currently being done in the app, all execution stops when this is first encountered  (i.e. I can't verify how many other instances of this may have occurred).

Comment: I also spent a little time and adding some debugging code which would count the total number of records to be inserted into the sqlite db, and then count the total number of results I get when I do a complete fetch request for all NSManagedObjects in Entity A - and the total number of NSManagedObjectContexts check out.

Comment: Are you using parent child contexts or thread confinement?

Comment: I am running into similar problem, I know it has been years but what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To answer your question as asked*: There is no set limit on how many managed objects can be in memory before a save is needed. Your application can create managed objects without saving as much as it wants, when memory is running low you will start to get the normal memory warnings that any iOS application can get. Ideally you do not want this to happen, and doing a context save or a context reset in reaction to a memory warning is probably not a very good idea either.

The scenarios you are describing in your details, however, are covered by Apple's documentation:

[Core Data Programming Guide: Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1)

And there is more that is relevant here:

[Core Data Programming Guide: Core Data Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW1)

In your case, you should be saving more often, and be doing work on more than one thread - you say you are only accessing storage from one thread, that is probably a large part of your problem right there. You do not seem to be getting changes from the context on thread A in the context on thread B - NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification is the primary way of doing that when using the older thread confinement model.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. The links you've provided are very useful, I'll be sure to give them a read.

One of the strangest things that we notice is, if we run an older version of the app (currently supported for iOS 5) against the same data set this problem doesn't appear. Please keep in mind that the older version of the app runs through the exact same component responsible for downloading, parsing and storing the json response in our SQLite persistent store.

Have there been any fundamental changes with CoreData in iOS 6?

Comment: Oh yes, many many changes. iOS 5 had a number of issues with CoreData that were resolved in iOS 6. It is possible that you are depending on that "broken" functionality somewhere. Speaking broadly, iOS 6 is doing things the right way. iOS 5 in a lot of places was not.

Comment: links are broken